# NSMutableString help Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablestring

I currently have the following code:

```
-(void) inputNumber:(int)number {

    NSString *str;

    str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
    [strVal appendString:str];
    txtShowNum.text = strVal;
}
```

I have already defined NSMutableString *strVal; before in my code.

When the function above executes the field remains blank, but if i were to use:

```
txtShowNum.text = str;
```

I get the value that I'm meant to but I obviously need the value concatenated.

Can anyone shed some light on this.

Thanks

Comment: When you say defined, do you mean it was initialized or just declared? Like: NSString* strVal = @""; ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should allocate an `NSMutableString` as well in your code, somewhere before this method is called.

E.g. like this:

```
-(void) inputNumber:(int)number {
    if ( strVal == nil ) strVal = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
    [strVal appendString:str];
    txtShowNum.text = strVal;
}
```

There are however some memory issues here. You'd better make `strVal` a retained property and then do:

```
    if ( self.strVal == nil ) self.strVal = [NSMutableString string];
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem of an output, but now when the method is called again it just crashes the app. Is there something in that code that will crash the app?

Comment: If the string is not retained, this code will crash the app. Do you have a line saying `@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString strVal;` in your header, and do you use `self.strVal = ...`? Then it shouldn't crash.

Comment: Thanks, that's what the problem was, it also needs @synthesize in the implementation, just a note if anyone else does come to read this question.

Answer (score 0):

Your `strVal` is most probably `nil`, so you call `appendString:` on nil which essentially does nothing at all, and setting the text field to nil will erase its contents.

Answer (score -4):

If you just declared it as a member variable, make sure you initialize it somewhere:

NSMutableString* strVal = @"";

If not, you are just calling a method on a nil object.

Comment: -1, `@""` is a statically allocated NSString, not a NSMutableString.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I posted this hastily. It should be NSMutableString* strVal = [NSMutableString alloc] init];

Comment: Which will lead to a memory leak if not handled properly, better use `[NSMutableString string]` to have it autoreleased. (or add a call to `autorelease`)